# What could cause remote drush commands to fail with ssh errors when ssh works in all other cases?

Tags: drush

I have public and private ssh keys on all of my three servers (dev, UAT, & production) so I can log in remotely, or from one to another.  Everything is working perfectly for the `ssh` and `scp` commands.

It does *not* work, however, for Drush.  If I execute `drush @dev status` from UAT, for example, I get the server's banner saying the system is "to be used by authorized users only *blah blah blah*", and then I get

> Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).

My `~/.drush/aliases.drushrc.php` file contains:

```
# Development #
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'uri' => 'http://default',
  'root' => '/var/www/vhosts/dev.www.company.com/current/',
  'remote-host' => 'companya0.company.com',
  'remote-user' => 'myusername'
);

# UAT #
$aliases['uat'] = array(
  'uri' => 'http://default',
  'root' => '/var/www/vhosts/uat.www.company.com/current/',
  'remote-host' => 'companyc6.company.com',
  'remote-user' => 'myusername'
);

# Production #
$aliases['prod'] = array(
  'uri' => 'http://default',
  'root' => '/var/www/vhosts/www.company.com/current/',
  'remote-host' => 'companyc1.company.com',
  'remote-user' => 'myusername'
);
```

***ONLY*** Drush has any problem using my ssh keys.
What could be preventing it from working?

Comment: I guess it depends which user Drush is being run from.  If Drush is being run by `www-data` (for example), then your SSH keys may be wrong/disallowed/non-whitelisted.

Comment: Run your drush commands with the -v or -s option to see the exact ssh command that Drush is generating for you. It should be clear from that what the difference is between the Drush invocation of ssh and your cli test of the same.

Comment: @Chapabu: Yes, I have to use `sudo` before `drush` and it appears everything is running as root (a security hole I've alerted the sysadmin about).  It appears that this is the problem.  I'm currently [looking for a solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50041/3358) while I wait for the sysadmin...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put this line in your drushrc.php file:

```
$options['ssh-options'] = '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /home/YOURUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa';
```

This will cause Drush to pass these options along to ssh any time it calls your remote system, so you can continue to call Drush via sudo, and still use your login user credentials.

Comment: Dude you're awesome...

Comment: Example for Windows: $options['ssh-options'] = '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i C:\users\laptop1\.ssh\id_rsa';

Comment: if correctly understood, the "/home/YOURUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa" dir is local to where the drush command is executed. The "home/YOURUSERNAME" dir is the $HOME dir and id_rsa is the private key iteself generated via ssh-keygen

Answer (score 1):

Check here: [How to run Drush as Apache](http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/blog/10-08-2012/how-to-run-drush-as-apache)

By the sound of it you just need to get the owner/group changed for Drush on your server!

Comment: This might be the ideal solution... but I'll have to get the sysadmin to agree before I can get things set up this way.