# standalone rsync and ssh work, but drush gets me a "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: drush

I've got a production site (on shared hosting for now) of which I just want to have backups at this stage. and I've got a backup instance which I want to overwrite with the prod site.

This is my /etc/drush/aliases.drushrc.php:

```
<?php
$aliases['bak'] = array(
        'root' => '/var/www/',
        'uri' => 'testvm',
        'db-url' => 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/drupal',
        'path-aliases' => array(
        '%dump' => '/var/bak.sql',
        '%files' => '/var/drupal_files',
      )
);

$aliases['prod'] = array(
        'root' => 'livesite.com:/home1/ruser/public_html/',
        'uri' => 'livesite.com',
        'db-url' => 'mysql://ruser:pass@localhost/drupal_drp3',
        'remote-user' => 'ruser',
        'path-aliases' => array(
        '%dump' => '/home1/ruser/prod.sql',
        '%files' => '/home1/ruser/drupal_files',
      )
);
?>
```

And all I'm getting through drush is:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
Could not rsync from livesite.com:/home1/ruser/public_html// to /var/www/        [error]
```

Even though I can rsync/ssh/scp with no issue to and from the live site. Certificates are in place, and working fine, but not for drush...

What I'm not seeing here???

PS I've seen [What could cause remote drush commands to fail with ssh errors when ssh works in all other cases?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45777/what-could-cause-remote-drush-commands-to-fail-with-ssh-errors-when-ssh-works-in), but the accepted answer does not make any difference for me.

**Update:**

I was using drush as root, so I tried creating a local user with same name as the remote user. I chowned the backup instance to the remote user.

```
ruser@drupal:~/.drush$ drush -v rsync @prod @bak
$options['ssh-options'] = '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /home/ruser/.ssh/id_rsa';

Loaded alias @prod from file /etc/drush/aliases.drushrc.php [notice]

Loaded alias @bak from file /etc/drush/aliases.drushrc.php [notice]
You will destroy data from /var/www/ and replace with data from livesite.com:/home1/ruser/public_html//
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Calling system(rsync -e 'ssh ' -akzv --exclude=".git" --exclude=".gitignore" --exclude=".hg" --exclude=".hgignore" --exclude=".hgrags" --exclude=".bzr" --exclude=".bzrignore" --exclude=".bzrtags" --exclude=".svn" --exclude="settings.php" --stats --progress livesite.com:/home1/ruser/public_html// /var/www/);
receiving incremental file list
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/var/www/.": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/var/www/.htaccess": Operation not permitted (1)
./

Number of files: 14547
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 92209263 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 313420
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 1017
Total bytes received: 316801

sent 1017 bytes  received 316801 bytes  42375.73 bytes/sec
total size is 92209263  speedup is 290.13
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1536) [generator=3.0.9]
Could not rsync from livesite.com:/home1/ruser/public_html// to /var/www/ [error]
Command dispatch complete
```

This user has certificates in place in the live site as well. But still no luck...

Comment: The answer you quote above should do the trick for you.  Run drush with the -s (simulate) flag to see exactly what shell commands Drush is using.  That should help you figure out why Drush is failing; once you get that far, post again if you can't figure out how to get Drush to emit the parameters you need for your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying a `remote-user` on `@bak` so who are you performing operations as on the server at @bak? You are also not specifying any ssh config options. In this case, you are asking @bak to authenticate with @prod via ssh/rsync but you are not using agent forwarding so @prod can't see your private key. Try specifying something like

```
'remote-user' => 'user_on_bak',
'ssh-options' => '-T',
```

So that drush will execute as 'user_on_bak' and ssh will pass along your local key to @bak so when it opens a session with @prod it will have a key to pass along.

Comment: almost to the day, 2 years after posted :) The site does not even exist any longer, so can't really test, but sounds like common sense to me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see what the permissions on `/var/www` and `/var/www/.htaccess` are.  try:

> ls -l /var/www /var/www/.htaccess

they should be writable.  You should be able to:

> touch /var/www/anewfile; touch /var/www/.htaccess

if you can't, then your local `ruser` user does not have permissions to those files.

> sudo chown -R ruser:ruser /var/www

to change ownership of all files under /var/www