# Drush aliases and Permission denied (publickey,password) problem

Tags: drush, ssh

Im trying to use Drush Aliases but getting Permission denied (publickey,password) error. I can login to server using publickey without password but Drush can not. 
I've read the solution mentioned [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45777/what-could-cause-remote-drush-commands-to-fail-with-ssh-errors-when-ssh-works-in) and made the change but no success. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible cause is that you are not specifying your remote user in the drush alias file.

For example, if the ssh command that works to allow you to login is:

```
ssh myuser@example.com
```

Then an alias might look like this:

```
$aliases['dev'] = array(
  'uri' => 'http://www.example.com',
  'root' => '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/docroot/',
  'remote-host' => 'example.com',
  'remote-user' => 'myuser'
);
```