# How to best handle "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"?

Tags: drush, ssh

I have custom Drush commands that contain shell commands with 'sudo' included. This results in an error when calling with remote alias to execute on remote instance:

```
drush @remote-alias custom-command-with-sudo
```

From research in google.com, I understand there is not tty session loaded when doing `ssh user@ssh-server` causing the error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48554/sudo-over-ssh-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/271186/how-do-i-resolve-the-tty-problem

Can I configure drush to include `-t` flag when its doing `ssh -t user@ssh-server`. I understand this will load tty session and solve problem, am i wrong?...in short, how do you best overcame this issue? Thank you

UPDATE:
I followed instructions from similar [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45777/what-could-cause-remote-drush-commands-to-fail-with-ssh-errors-when-ssh-works-in) referred by Clive

1. Added following line in `.drush/drushrc.php`:

   ```
   $options['ssh-options'] = '-o PasswordAuthentication=no -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa/lamp_vbox';
   ```
2. Then I run in debug mode by adding --debug and this is what it shows:

> Calling proc_open(ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -i /Users/owner/.ssh/id_rsa/lamp_vbox margots@lamp-vbox 'COLUMNS=179 drush  --debug --uri=dev-metronic --root=/home/websites/dev/metronic --verbose  deploy-asset '\''@dev-metronic'\''   --ver=0.3 --asset=metronic --env=dev 2>&1' 2>&1);
>           Starting Drush preflight. [0.06 sec, 1.51 MB]

From the log, I conclude that the settings are being passed, however. I still get the error, so I wonder what could be the problem and how to solve it.

I'm using: Mac 10.9, Drush Version   :  7.0-dev

Comment: I think I recall seeing a similar question here once upon a time with an answer that suggested there wasn't a way to pass custom ssh flags...or maybe it was the other way round. I'll see if I can dig it out

Comment: Ah it was the other way around, [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45777/what-could-cause-remote-drush-commands-to-fail-with-ssh-errors-when-ssh-works-in) should help

Comment: thank you Clive. It doesn't seem to work. I am updating the question with instructions of the proposed solution

Answer (score 1):

This may not be solution for everyone, but it worked in my situation because i could change settings at the remote instance. I followed [the following instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password/443071#443071) and turned on `NOPASSWORD`, which is adding the following line into sudoers file:

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Afterwards, my custom drush commands with sudo works on the remote instance